# Which HTML content type to return data and avoid my line feeds being banalized into spaces

Tags: text, web, content-type

I am running a small web server in python (cherrypy). I wish to return data of the following format:

```
20100701,1.5127
20100702,1.5184
20100705,1.51075
```

So at the moment my python looks like that in order to test the output:

```
return """20100701,1.5127
20100702,1.5184
20100705,1.51075
"""
```

When I request the URL from my other end, the one supposed to use the data, and expecting to parse line by line, I get the following output:

```
20100701,1.5127 20100702,1.5184 20100705,1.51075
```

Line feeds have been replaced by spaces... I guess this might be because my server considers I am sending html, so ignores my line feeds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the content type of the response to `text/plain`.